# How should one handle dependencies among Play sub-projects?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, sbt, playframework-2.1

After creating a huge mess of a Play project, I decided that it would probably be a good idea to break it into sub-projects so that the dependencies are, I can compile part of the project, etc.

Unfortunately, I'm discovering that the sub-projects have slight dependencies on the whole project. The coupling is small enough that I'm not ashamed of it, but SBT won't let me declare circular dependencies. (And I think that's a good thing.)

Here's an example. I have a `users` sub-project that defines several models for dealing with users. There are also basic views that you would probably expect for dealing with users: login, logout, changePassword, updateSettings, etc. The problem is, these all depend on my main template so that they look like the rest of the site. So I need some way to let the users sub-project know what the main template is that it should embed its views in.

As another example, most sites have a "default" page that they send users to when they try to access information they're not authorized to access, or after they logout, etc. The sub-projects need to know what that page is so they can redirect to the default page as needed. But the default page is defined in the main project, which the sub-projects can't depend on.

I started trying to solve this problem by using my Global.onStart method in the main project to "inject" settings into the sub-projects. For example, I created a `var` to hold the default page, and then set `controllers.users.App.defaultPage` to the right value when the application started. But then I realized that every sub-project is going to need a few hooks to tell it how it fits into the main project, and trying to manually keep track of all this was just asking for trouble.

Has anyone come up with a good way of dealing with this issue? Should each sub-project have a default `Configuration` that the main project can modify? Is there a way for each sub-project to declare what configuration it needs, so that the main project failing to provide it would trigger an error? Should I be ashamed at how coupled my code is, and go back to the drawing board?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a good question, and one which I've been grappling with lately. Sub-projects are a nice way to make a Play app more manageable, but I'm finding it's very difficult to accomplish in practice without lots of hacks involving mutable configuration.

Comment: We have some config injection, but no mutation. Why are you having make your config mutable?

Comment: At this point, expediency, pretty much! I'll investigate a DI solution when everything is working nicely; a mutable map populated in the onStart handler was just the quickest way to proof-of-concept this thing. Would be interested to hear more specifics of your case if you have a github link or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more searching, I came across this blog entry. I'm going to give this a shot and see how it works:

http://eng.42go.com/play-framework-dependency-injection-guice/

After using this for a couple of weeks, it's been mostly a success. There are still chicken/egg problems to work out, but I think that's because I hadn't really thought through how much each of my sub-projects depended on others.

There's still no really easy way to access routes from parts of projects you don't depend on, but you probably shouldn't be linking to projects you don't depend on, anyway. I did figure out how to specify a main template and urls/calls for things like my "Not Found", "Permission Required", and "Login" pages so that all sub-projects could access them.